# Command not found- bash : sqlplus:

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus

I'm trying to use sqlplus in Oracle database docker container (for `Windows 10`).

Commands given:

```
"docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 --name OracleDB store/oracle/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1"
"docker start OracleDB"
"docker exec -it OracleDB bash"
"sqlplus / as sysdba"
```

And now I get the error message:

> ```
> "bash: sqlplus: command not found"
> ```

[image: Image01]

[image: image02]

Comment: What is your ORACLE_HOME directory?

Comment: [oracle@fdbf97e3a5fe /]$ ls

ORCL  boot  etc   lib    media  opt   root  sbin  sys  u01  u03  usr
bin   dev   home  lib64  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  u02  u04  var

[oracle@fdbf97e3a5fe /]$

- If this is what you asked?

Comment: this is not what I am asking... You need ORALE_HOME dir before proceeding to next step.  I know what your problem is  but I cannot help you without knowing your ORACLE_HOME directory

Comment: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1

Answer (score 8):

Try with this:

```
"docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 --name OracleDB store/oracle/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1"
"docker start OracleDB"
"docker exec -it OracleDB bash"
"/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba"
```

Answer (score 3):

While with @dervis answer it is possible to start SQL Plus, it introduced further issues on my side such as `ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact` or `Connected to an idle instance.`

What it solved for me is updating the `PATH` environment variable as shown below:

```
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112702/bash-sqlplus-command-not-found

Afterwards I was able to start SQL Plus as usual with:

```
source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connect to container:

```
docker exec -u oracle -it OracleDB bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash -l -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32700631)

Answer (score 0):

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash -l -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
```

This is working for me