# Oracle Docker install - bash: sqlplus: command not found

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle12c

I am  trying to install Oracle with Docker.

I followed Docker documentation:

> Oracle Database Enterprise Edition | Tue Aug 25 2020 Oracle Database
> Server Docker Image Documentation" from docker.

I run

```
docker exec -it oracle bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"
```

And I got this error:

```
bash: sqlplus: command not found
```

I tried

[Command not found- bash : sqlplus:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400134/command-not-found-bash-sqlplus)